# In Python, how do I force "datetime.strptim" to use a timezone?

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I'm parsing some strings into dates using this logic ...

```
created_on = datetime.strptime(created_on_txt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')
print(created_on.tzinfo)
```

How do I incorporate the fact that the time zone I want to be interpreted for the string shoudl be UTC?  When I print out the ".tzinfo," it reads "None."  An example of something I'm parsing is

```
2019-04-08T17:03:00+00:00
```

Comment: I think parsing `+00:00` directly will cause `strptime` to ignore it. Try playing with either `%z` or `%Z` format specifiers: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @quiet_laika, yup it was "%z"

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7, [lucky you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat):

```
created_on = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-04-08T17:03:00+00:00')
created_on.tzinfo
>>> datetime.timezone.utc
```

If you insist on using `strptime()`:

```
created_on = datetime.strptime('2019-04-08T17:03:00+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
created_on.tzinfo
>>> datetime.timezone.utc
```

This uses the [%z directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).